# How to display validation message only once with all error messages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am Creating dynamic form submit function in jquery

```js
$('#btnsumbit').click(function() {
  $('.required_field').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
      alert('please fill field');
      return false;
    }
  });
  $('.email_check').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
      alert('please provide valid email');
      return false;
    }
  });
  $('.number_check').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {

      alert('please provide valid number');
      return false;
    }
  });
  alert("All Are Ok");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But When i click the button first it shows the all are OK alert box,
it is wrong,

My requirement is after complete all each loop i need alert box,

Any Solution For this or Any other Possible way for solving this problem,
Thanks..

Comment: because returning false in `.each` function doesn't stop program flow

Comment: Or maybe all your selectors select nothing and `each` does not run. Btw - what does `php` do here?

Comment: if anything error in first each function means its showing error perfectly. but  no error in first loop means in that time only it's showing the alert box

Comment: @u_mulder no use of php here? i send all field data to ajax.For that I am using jquery method

Comment: And what? Your question is about `javascript`. Then add `html`, `css`, `mysql` don't you use them too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you correctly replacing your snippet with following will help in achieve what you require

```js
$('#btnsumbit').click(function() {
  var validationMsg = ""
  $('.required_field').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
      validationMsg = validationMsg + 'please fill field \n'
      return false;
    }
  });
  $('.email_check').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
      validationMsg = validationMsg + ' please provide valid email \n' ;
      return false;
    }
  });
  $('.number_check').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
      validationMsg = validationMsg + ' please provide valid number \n';
      return false;
    }
  });
  if(validationMsg == "") {
    alert("All Are Ok"); 
  } else {
    alert(validationMsg);
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So in case of empty fields message will be `""All Are Ok please fill field"`?

Comment: Also `validateionMsg` and `validationMsg` are different vars.

Comment: @u_mulder can you pls check now

Comment: @prabhakar it is some typos i just fixed it